# Automatic Scrolling in a Silverlight List Box with Custom Template

Tags: silverlight, listbox, controltemplate

I have ListBox with custom template, how do programmatically scroll it down to bottom?

[Automatic Scrolling in a Silverlight List Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928204/automatic-scrolling-in-a-silverlight-list-box) describes method of scrolling to bottom of ListBox. Unfortunately this method does not work with ListBox with custom style template.

Have anyone success to scroll ListBox with custom style?

Problem code:

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="HorizontalWrapListBox" TargetType="ListBox">
        <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
                        <ScrollViewer>
                            <ItemsPresenter />
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style.Setters>
    </Style>
</Grid.Resources>

<ListBox x:Name="MyListBox" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
         Style="{StaticResource HorizontalWrapListBox}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432" Height="78">
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineOne}" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                         Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineTwo}" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                         Margin="12,-6,12,0" 
                         Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
             </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep correct naming of your template parts and this could just start working. The ScrollViewer should be named x:Name="ScrollViewer". Check

1. [ListBox Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278062%28v=vs.95%29.aspx),
2. [Customizing the Appearance of an Existing Control by Using a ControlTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189093%28v=vs.95%29.aspx),
3. [TemplatePartAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.templatepartattribute%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, Man! It works perfectly! Sadly i cannot vote for answer due my reputation :-[