# WP7 Listbox - How to ensure selected item is visible via Binding

Tags: windows-phone-7, data-binding, listbox, mvvm-light

Using MVVM Light I have a listbox databound to a collection of several items.
One of the items is the selected one.

With this code it works perfectly and ViewModel structures are updated correctly:

```
 <Name="listBox1"
 ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Models}"
 SelectedItem="{Binding Path=csProfile.Model, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

My problem is that when I enter the page if the selected Item is not in the first items it is not visible and the user does not know what was the previous selection.

How could I force the Listbox to always show the Selected Item?

Possibly via properties or Binding.

M

Answer (score 0):

There's no property you can bind to to set what's visible. Instead call `ScrollToVerticalOffset()` on the ScrollViewer inside the ListBox.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the ScrollIntoView method.  A similar topic was discussed here:
[Automatic Scrolling in a Silverlight List Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928204/automatic-scrolling-in-a-silverlight-list-box)

The API reference is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.scrollintoview(VS.95).aspx

Calling UpdateLayout() before calling ScrollIntoView on the selected item seems to be necessary.

Comment: I've tried to add the following code: `private void listBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
  {
   listBox1.UpdateLayout();
   listBox1.ScrollIntoView(listBox1.SelectedItem ); 
  }` but it does not work

Comment: I've found a workaround: I put the update in an event of the continer control.